# Відповідник до слова "багет"

Tags: іменники, відповідник

Цікавить, чи є відповідник до слова "багет". У [цьому](https://www.dictionaries24.com/uk/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82) і [цьому](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82) словнику інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайті [Cловотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bahet) знаходимо такі відповідники:

> французький батон, фруханець, батон-перекуска, французький хліб.

Також  ще одне значення цього слова знаходимо у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/baghet):

> **БАГЕ́Т,** а, чол. Пофарбована або позолочена планка, з якої виготовляють рами, карнизи або яку використовують для скріплення і оздоблення стелі, стін і т. ін.

В  цьому значенні український відповідник знайти важко, хіба що використовувати ціле означення.

Comment: Додам, що варіант _французький батон_ [уживається в книжках](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&%22французький+батон%22) (можливо, це буде надійнішим джерелом за «Словотвір»).

Answer (score 3):

У «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах:

> [БАГЕ́Т](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=2183&page=96), а, ч[оловічий рід]. <…>
>
> 2. Різновид білого хліба — **довгий батон**. Дуже популярним елементом французької кухні є, безсумнівно, багет (з наук.-попул. літ.).

Відповідно за бажання запобігти використанню слова *багет* пропоную вживати *довгий батон* (якщо Ви мали на увазі саме це значення).

Answer (score 2):

Варто зазначити, що слово "батон" також має [французьке походження](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD). Тому вже буде краще, якщо ми замінимо "багет" словами "**французький хліб**" ([Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bahet)) чи "**французька булка**" (все та ж Вікіпедія, а також [Глобс](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82)).

Звичайно, проблема залишається у тому як перекласти різновиди багетів, бо я не впевнений, що "Селянська французька булка" буде хорошим відповідником слова "селянський багет". І все ж, як варіант можна використовувати приклади, які я навів вище.

Уся моя відповідь стосується слова "багет" у значенні: "Традиційний французький хлібо-булочний виріб. "

А взагалі, я задав схоже питання стосовно "хот-дога", після чого зрозумів, що досить складно перекласти назви страв чи продуктів, які є традиційними для тієї чи іншої народної кухні, ми ж не перекладаємо такі слова як "піца", "стейк", а іноземцям важко знайти відповідник до наших "вареників" та "борщу".

Comment: Проблема зі словосполученням **французька булка**, а також його синонімом **франзо́ля** (який хоч, здається, і не є загальновживаним, але [міститься в словнику Грінченка й інших](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=франзоля) й [уважається одеським діалектизмом](//books.google.com/books?id=kk0ZAQAAIAAJ&q=французька+булка)) у тому, що вони можуть позначати не лише власне багет (дуже видовжену булку), а й округлу за французьким рецептом теж (див. [1](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/французская_булка), [2](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/Франзоля)).